# Javascript onclick not calling the function on <img>

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have an image gallery and on clicking on each of the image I have flipped a the image with some info about the image. My issue is the `onclick` which I have applied is not calling the function and there is no error coming up on `console.log`. What could be the possible reason, any insight will be really helpful.Stuck on this simple issue but clueless.

```html
<div class="column">
  <img src="img/image.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="openNav1();">
  <div class="overlay" id="myNav1">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="text">Info</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function openNav1() {
    console.log('in herre');
    document.getElementById("myNav1").style.display = "block";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav1").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: So you're not seeing the `'in here'` text appear?

Comment: Yeah. Actually its not at all getting into `openNav1()`

Comment: Are you sure? if you run the code snippet and click the image it will run the code in `openNav1()`

Comment: The snippet seems to be working fine (with clicking on the Alt text since there's no image)

Comment: Ohh. I am not understanding why is it not working in my code

Comment: @Ansh If its not working on your end, Try to create JSFiddle to show the code not working.

Comment: What could be the possible cases when onclick event does not calls a function at all?

Answer (score 1):

Bro, you have an `div.overlay`.. I suppose it covers the image and therefore u may not click the `<img />` since it is always under the `div.overlay`. One possible solution is to apply `pointer-events: none` to the `.overlay`

Comment: Thanks for this . But still no outcome . Anything else can be done?

Comment: Have you checked with the inspector if this is the case.

Comment: Actually the images are not at all clickable even if I am putting `<a>` around  the image at the very basic level. What could be the possible case for such issue

Comment: Apply `pointer-events: auto` on the `<img>`. Also check if something covers them.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript Was Working But You Didn't knew Because It's Display Style Was Already

**Block** So I Changed Display To **None** And Did A Small Change For You In The JavaScript Hope

You Like It.

**CloseNav();** Function isn't Necessary Because Now **#myNav1** Opens & Closes By Clicking On The Image.

```
<div class="column">
    <img id="img"  src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg"  height='250px' alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onClick="openNav1();" />
     <div style='display:none' class="overlay" id="myNav1">
  <a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="text">Info</div>
  </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openNav1() {
var mynav = document.getElementById("myNav1");
var img = document.getElementById("img");

  img.style.cursor = "pointer";
  if (mynav.style.display == "block") {
  mynav.style.display = "none";
  } else {
  mynav.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav1").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but no gain with this. Its still not calling the function. Something else  can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using with anchor tag

```
<a onclick="openNav1();"><img src="img/image.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" > </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but still no result. I am just amazed of the fact that why is it not getting into the javascript function.